# When app is onPause my DialogFragment is shown multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a custom dialog in my App and i actually open it from my fragment like this:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
btnScarica = view.findViewById(R.id.btnScarica)
            btnScarica.setOnClickListener {
            ScaricoDialog(articoliViewModel.articoli.value?.size).show(parentFragmentManager, "DialogScarico")
        }
}
```

While the ScaricoDialog.kt looks like this:

```
class ScaricoDialog(private val listSize: Int? = 0): DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        dialog!!.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.round_corner)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.scarica_dialog, container, false)
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val width = (resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.85).toInt()
        dialog!!.window?.setLayout(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    }
}
```

When i lock the device so the app goes onPause and i unblock it i find lot of that dialogs open even when i opened just one...

i solved it by setting this onPause in my DialogFragment:

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    dialog?.dismiss()
}
```

But is it normal? is my solution right to do so?

Comment: When do you launch the dialog ? Could you share code?

Comment: @rogalz added the code, it's inside a onClick in my onViewCreated

Answer (score -1):

set Dialog show method in onActivityCreate inside fragment method like this and **stop dismiss in on pause**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       val width = (resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.85).toInt()
       dialog!!.window?.setLayout(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
ScaricoDialog(articoliViewModel.articoli.value?.size).show(parentFragmentManager, "DialogScarico")
    }
```

Comment: that will open the dialog each time the fragment is created when i show the dialog onClick